# Merge cells for empty values in PDF Form table?

Tags: javascript, adobe, abap, livecycle-designer, pdf-form

I try to make pdf table like this:

[image: PdfTableExample]

I need:

- if header1 and header2 in line is null - make only left border (or right for header2)
- else make all border except bottom.

Why when header1 and header2 is null? I cannot see left/right border.

My code is:

- For header1:

  ```
        data.#subform[0].Table1.Row1.MANDT::ready:layout - (JavaScript, client)
    //"0" is the top border, 
    //"1" is the right border, 
    //"2" = bottom and 
    //"3" is the left border
    if ( this.rawValue == null )
    {
    //TextField.Border
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        this.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
        this.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";



    }
    else 
    {
    ////TextField.Border
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //  this.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
        this.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";
    }
  ```
- For header2:

  ```
     data.#subform[0].Table1.Row1.MATNR::ready:layout - (JavaScript, client)
    //"0" is the top border, 
    //"1" is the right border, 
    //"2" = bottom and 
    //"3" is the left border
    if ( this.rawValue == null )
    {
    //TextField.Border
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        this.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
        this.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";



    }
    else 
    {
    ////TextField.Border
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //  this.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "invisible";
        this.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
    //  this.ui.oneOfChild.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "invisible";
    }
  ```

Comment: sandra rossi ... return back abap tag to the post. It's not js question. if you don't understand different between it, stop lost the point of my question.

Comment: I cannot. it's a Adobe LiveCycle issue in ABAP formular. In js this code work perfectly. I cannot make new tag "Adobe LiveCycle" and she have not  enough skills for understand my question. js colleagues cannot help me, because code work correct.

Comment: Please refine your question: debug your JS code to see what's going on. After that, post your ABAP code and that will make it an ABAP question. Thank you.

Comment: `I cannot make new tag "Adobe LiveCycle"` i added tags https://stackoverflow.com/tags/livecycle-designer and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf-form to your question, do NOT create new tags unless you are absolutely sure that you searched it well and none was found

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd header make sure the edge 1 and edge 3 borders are set to visible

```
if ( this.rawValue == null || this.rawValue == "" || this.rawValue == " " )
{
this.border.getElement("edge",0).presence = "invisible";
this.border.getElement("edge",1).presence = "visible";
this.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
this.border.getElement("edge",3).presence = "visible";
}
else
{
this.border.getElement("edge",2).presence = "invisible";
}
```